# How euphemistic is 傢伙?

Tags: usage, nuance, euphemism

傢伙 (an example of a Chinese lexeme that does not map bijectively between simplified and traditional characters, the simplified word being 家伙) is translated, [in the only translation Wang Xiaobo's work has received to date](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Wang-Love-Bondage-Xiaobo/dp/0791470652), as 'tool.' Which would indicate that the word is a euphemism (委婉语) for penis in the following.

> 从派出所到居委会，都认为他是个好贼，舍不得送他进监狱，只可惜他偷得太多，最后只好把他枪毙掉，这使派出所的警察和居委会的老大妈一齐掉眼泪。这个贼临死还留下遗嘱，把尸体捐给医院了。我有个同学考上了医科大学，常在福尔马林槽里看到他。他说，那位贼兄的家伙特别大，躺在水槽里仪表堂堂，丝毫也看不出是个贼，虽然后脑勺上挨了一枪，但不翻身也看不出来。

— *2015* by 王小波.

But how euphemistic?

Because the English word 'tool', while euphemistic, is also a bit cheeky. It's even an insult. It's not detached, scientific-sounding, or fantastical, like other euphemisms for things.

Does 傢伙 carry those nuances? (I have to admit, it sounds just a bit scientific-sounding and detached to me. But obviously I'm not a native speaker.)

In other words, has the pair of translators captured something of a nuance here? Or has meaning been added, or lost?

Comment: At first I thought your question was all in Chinese, considering the preview... :D

Comment: You might want to move your first paragraph above the quote to make the preview more informative, even for Chinese speakers.

Comment: Or add an extra introducing sentence like "Consider this paragraph/excerpt/etc...", something like that.

Comment: @DonKirkby & Alenanno, if you think this makes it a better question, you can always edit it!  I've done so for this post.

Comment: I like to be a gentle moderator, @brc.

Comment: @brc寇百强 I chose to ask so he would provide the best intro for his question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the nuance carried the English word "tool". But according to your description, I don't think there's such nuance in Wang's article. It is just a normal euphemism, with no added meaning to the original word (penis).

Basically, 傢伙 would carry a similar connotation as "manhood" or "member" (maybe without the informality associated with "member").